# How to build up an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, collections

Having trouble building up the profiles `IEnumerable`.  `Mapper.Initialize` needs to run only once with all the profiles in the project.  Tried setting `profiles = new List<Profile>()`, but profiles count was always 0.

```
IEnumerable<Profile> profiles = null;
var profileType = typeof(Profile);
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("Cars.Data"));
foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    profiles.Concat(
       assembly.GetTypes()
           .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                  t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
           .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
           .Cast<Profile>());
}

Mapper.Initialize(c => profiles.ForEach(c.AddProfile));
```

Comment: Always explain what didn't work, specifically.  "It didn't work" by itself means very little to us.

Comment: Aren't you getting an `ArgumentNullException` from `profiles.Concat()`?  You aren't allowed to Concat with a null object.  If that is your issue why not make it a `List<Profile>` and use `.AddRange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`profiles.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  gives an `ArgumentNullException` when using with a null.  Since you are setting the list to null you will get this error.  Your solution is to use a List and the AddRange method as follws

```
List<Profile> profiles = new List<Profile>();
profiles.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes()
           .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                  t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
           .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
           .Cast<Profile>());
```

Comment: Ah, right.  I didn't realize List<T> implements IEnumerable<T>.  Should have used a list.  BTW: Change your answer to new up the list on the first line.

Answer (score 7):

`IEnumerable<T>` is immutable.

`.Concat()` returns a new `IEnumerable<T>` with the concatenated sequence; you are ignoring this result.

Comment: That's nice, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @O.O, well, it does. Completely and fully, except for your first `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @flindeberg - the answer that I'm looking for is one that makes my code work, not a dictionary answer. Harrison is on the right track.

Comment: @O.O Ie `IEnumerable<T>` is immutable. In all honesty, you have not researched your question.

Comment: I didn't ask if IEnumerable<T> was immutable.  I asked how to build one up.  The answer is use a List.  In all honesty, did you research the question?

Comment: @O.O This is why you should [explain why your code isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794813/how-to-build-up-an-ienumerable#comment29425991_19794813).  When you don't explain what is giving you problems people are forced to guess as to what's wrong.  They may guess right, they may guess wrong.  If you *explain* what your problem is, then they don't need to guess.

Comment: @Servy - I did explain about 10 seconds after your comment.  I made an edit.

Comment: @O.O, The answer is not to use a `List`, the answer is to understand what you are asking. `Enumerable<T>.Empty` as an initer would have been splendid. Your problem is not taking the immutability of `IEnumerable<T>` into account and just throwing the value away.

Comment: @flindeberg - fair enough.  I admit that I don't know that much about IEnumerable and immutable and all that stuff.  I still need more detail from SLaks as it applies to my code snippet.

Comment: @O.O Which actually is my point, SO is not for providing code snippets for general coding mistakes, it is providing good solutions. My point is that you should have read up on `IEnumerable<T>` before asking since your actual problem is trivial and non-specific.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @SLaks perfectly correct answer I will here present a proper LINQ-solution. But the problem in itself is that the OP did not assign his new built lazy-expression (well, monad).

```
var profileType = typeof(Profile);
var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("Cars.Data"))
    .SelectMany(a => 
           a.GetTypes()
           .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                  t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
           .Select(Activator.CreateInstance) // Have you overloaded this?
           .Cast<Profile>())
     .ToList(); // ToList enumerates
```

or even more easier to read:

```
var profileType = typeof(Profile);
var profiles = 
     from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
     where a.FullName.Contains("Cars.Data")
     from t in a.GetTypes()
     where profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
       and t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
     select (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance; // Have you overloaded this?

var profileList = profiles.ToList(); // Enumerate if needed.
```

The whole idea of LINQ (and `IEnumerable<T>`) is to not use the explicit classes and constructors.